# Drop-down navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I have seen a number of websites where, if I connect from a mobile device, the navigation bar automatically changes to a drop-down menu. This prevents the navigation bar being displayed too small, or off he side of the screen, or on two rows instead of one.

Now, the drop-down menu always seems to be a button with three horizontal lines on it, and feels very consistent across diffferent websites with this feature. For this reason, I'm wondering whether this is some built-in feature in CSS which automatically converts the navigation at into a drop-down menu, when appropriate. If so, could somebody point me towards info on how I might be able to incorporate this into my own website?

Thanks.

Comment: This can be a Bootstrap navigation bar. [Bootstrap navbar reference](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Comment: user bootstrap or create your own

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wexd3spp/19/

Answer (score 0):

you have add media query for this
**HTML**

```
<img class="show-menu" src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/themename/images/menu.png" alt="">
<nav class="main-nav">  
<div class="menu-primary-menu-container">
<ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="menu">
<li ><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
<li><a href="#>menu1</a></li>
<li ><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
<li ><a href="#">menu1</a></li>

</ul></div>                                      
</nav>
```

**Media Query CSS**

```
    @media(max-width:640px){
    .show-menu {
        display: block;
    }
    .main-nav {
        left: 0;
        padding-top: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .menu-primary-menu-container {
        display: none;
    }
    .main-nav:hover .menu-primary-menu-container {
        display: block;
    }
    }

@media(min-width:641px){
.show-menu {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is call "habmubrger menu".
It is combination of CSS and JS.
You can find it http://getbootstrap.com/ .
Or you can build it yourself. It is simple

Also check media queries